# How can I call a bitmap defined in a method of another class?

Tags: android, variables, methods, public

I want to call a bitmap from a method in my main class and am unsure how to do it -

I have a method:

```
private void detectFaces() {
Bitmap bitmap565 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Config.RGB_565);    


if (facesFound < 1) {

                Intent k = new Intent(main.this, False.class);
                startActivity(k);
```

and in my False.class I have:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detectfalse);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.false_view);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badPicText);
        textView.setText(R.string.noFace);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
```

So basically, how can I place the bitmap in my detectFaces method in my main class and pass it as a bitmap on my imageview in my false class?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the way it should be done, but for the sake of answering, Just make `bitmap565`  a `public static` variable. You can then Access it using `Main.bitmap565`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was weird to read... anyway, you can't pass `Bitmaps` between activities. What I see here is that the bitmap is too simple (Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);), so why don't you create the bitmap in your `False` activity? If your bitmap is not that simple, you will have to pass other kind of data. For instance, you could pass the URL of the bitmap, and then decode it on your False class:

```
Intent k = new Intent(main.this, False.class);
k.putExtra("the_url", "http://blablabla");
startActivity(k);
```

It was just an example to show how you pass data between activities. You can use that data using: `getIntent().getStringExtra("the_url")`.

Comment: The bitmap is just assigned the picture that the user took.  You were actually helping me yesterday with content Views ;).  I used your advice but my code is still not going to be contentViews...

Comment: I actually posted my issue here if you could please take a look:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227842/having-trouble-setting-content-view-to-a-specific-layout

Thanks!

Comment: So... if the user took the picture... how are you creating the bitmap? I mean, what are you using to create the bitmap. It's important that you provide that info (a bitmap can be create in too many different ways). Also... if you are using the normal intents to take the picture, you can use the Uri directly and assign it to the ImageView instead of creating bitmaps.